# Missing dates for specific identifiers without adding extra dates when this identifier is no longer in the database SQL

Tags: sql, presto

To put the problem in words, I have a massive table which includes subscribers and data for every day. If the subscriber no longer exists, then they will have no more records i.e. SUB123 no longer exists from the 28/10/2021 then this subscriber will have records up every day until 27/10/2021. The problem at hand is that some subscribers have missing dates and this could perhaps be as it is a weekend or other problems. I want to fill these records with null values so that they could be on record.

The current problem:

| Subscriber | Date | Rev |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sub123 | 25/10/2021 | 256 |
| sub456 | 25/10/2021 | 282 |
| sub123 | 26/10/2021 | 652 |
| sub123 | 27/10/2021 | 396 |
| sub456 | 28/10/2021 | 132 |
| sub456 | 29/10/2021 | 484 |
| sub456 | 01/11/2021 | 96 |
| sub456 | 02/11/2021 | 45 |

The desired solution:

| Subscriber | Date | Rev |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sub123 | 25/10/2021 | 256 |
| sub456 | 25/10/2021 | 282 |
| sub123 | 26/10/2021 | 652 |
| sub456 | 26/10/2021 | NULL |
| sub123 | 27/10/2021 | 396 |
| sub456 | 27/10/2021 | NULL |
| sub456 | 28/10/2021 | 132 |
| sub456 | 29/10/2021 | 484 |
| sub456 | 30/10/2021 | NULL |
| sub456 | 31/10/2021 | NULL |
| sub456 | 01/11/2021 | 96 |
| sub456 | 02/11/2021 | 45 |

My current attempt:

```
WITH all_dates as (
SELECT
     CAST(date_column AS DATE) date_column, b.subscriber, b.date
FROM
 (VALUES
     (SEQUENCE(
      min(b.date) OVER (PARTITION BY b.subscriber ORDER BY b.date),
      max(b.date) OVER (PARTITION BY b.subscriber ORDER BY b.date),
      INTERVAL '1' DAY)
     )
 ) AS t1(date_array)
CROSS JOIN
 UNNEST(date_array) AS t2(date_column) 
LEFT JOIN MAINTABLE b 
on t2.date_column = b.date
), 
customer_dates as (
SELECT distinct a.subscriber, a.date, b.date_column
from MAINTABLE a
left join all_dates b
on a.date = b.date_column
    )
    SELECT *
    from customer_dates a
```

This code doesn't work but its an attempt to what I am trying to accomplish if I were to use the following code that is attached below it will generate dates for all subscribers from the initial date to the end date which is not what we want hence why the above code is what was attempted.

```
WITH all_dates as (
SELECT
     CAST(date_column AS DATE) date_column, b.subscriber, b.date
FROM
 (VALUES
     (SEQUENCE(
      date('2021-10-25'),
      date('2022-04-30'),
      INTERVAL '1' DAY)
     )
 ) AS t1(date_array)
CROSS JOIN
 UNNEST(date_array) AS t2(date_column) 
LEFT JOIN MAINTABLE b 
on t2.date_column = b.date
), 
customer_dates as (
SELECT distinct a.subscriber, a.date, b.date_column
from MAINTABLE a
left join all_dates b
on a.date = b.date_column
    )
    SELECT *
    from customer_dates a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag` function to generate missing ranges to flatten with `unnest` and handle `Rev` additionally:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (Subscriber, Date, Rev) AS (
    VALUES ('sub123',   date_parse('25-10-2021', '%d-%m-%Y'),   256),
    ('sub456',  date_parse('25-10-2021', '%d-%m-%Y'),   282),
    ('sub123',  date_parse('26-10-2021', '%d-%m-%Y'),   652),
    ('sub123',  date_parse('27-10-2021', '%d-%m-%Y'),   396),
    ('sub456',  date_parse('28-10-2021', '%d-%m-%Y'),   132),
    ('sub456',  date_parse('29-10-2021', '%d-%m-%Y'),   484),
    ('sub456',  date_parse('01-11-2021', '%d-%m-%Y'),   96),
    ('sub456',  date_parse('02-11-2021', '%d-%m-%Y'),   45)
) 

-- query
select subscriber, lifted_date as date, if(date = lifted_date, rev, NULL) rev
from
(
    select Subscriber, 
        Rev,
        cast(date as date) date, 
        lag(cast(date as date)) over(partition by Subscriber order by date) prev_date
    from dataset
)
cross join unnest(
        array_except(sequence(coalesce(prev_date, date), date, interval '1' day), array[prev_date])
    ) as t(lifted_date)
order by subscriber, date
```

Output:

| subscriber | date | rev |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sub123 | 2021-10-25 00:00:00.000 | 256 |
| sub123 | 2021-10-26 00:00:00.000 | 652 |
| sub123 | 2021-10-27 00:00:00.000 | 396 |
| sub456 | 2021-10-25 00:00:00.000 | 282 |
| sub456 | 2021-10-26 00:00:00.000 |  |
| sub456 | 2021-10-27 00:00:00.000 |  |
| sub456 | 2021-10-28 00:00:00.000 | 132 |
| sub456 | 2021-10-29 00:00:00.000 | 484 |
| sub456 | 2021-10-30 00:00:00.000 |  |
| sub456 | 2021-10-31 00:00:00.000 |  |
| sub456 | 2021-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 96 |
| sub456 | 2021-11-02 00:00:00.000 | 45 |

Comment: Thanks this is what I am looking for, lets say there are multiple columns for REV, should I just repeat the IF condition for all columns?

Comment: @WailAli if you need nulls using provided solution - I'm afraid yes. If there are to much fields you can try to combine your join approach with the provided one (use it only to generate `subscriber` -> `date` columns).