# Query a 30 day interval for every 30 day interval in the last year

Tags: sql, for-loop, presto

I want to query every 30 day interval in 2021, but I don't know how to do it without a for loop in SQL.

Here's psuedo code of what I want to do with a table called `_table` and a date column called `application_date`:

```
for _day in range(335):
    select '2021-01-01' + _day as start_date, count(*) as _count
    from _table
    where '2021-01-01' + _day <= application_date <= ('2021-01-01' + _day + interval '30' day )
```

It would output something like this:

| start_date | _count |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | {number of rows between 2021-01-01 and 2021-01-31} |
| 2021-01-02 | {number of rows between 2021-01-02 and 2021-02-01} |
| ... | ... |
| 2021-11-31 | {number of rows between 2021-11-31 and 2021-12-30} |
| 2021-12-01 | {number of rows between 2021-12-01 and 2021-12-31} |

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have rows for each day you can group data by date, count it in the group and then use `sum` [window function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html) with range of 30 rows (current + next 30 rows, note that *{rows between 2021-01-01 and 2021-01-31}* have interval of 31 day, not 30):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(start_date) AS (
    VALUES (date '2021-01-01'),
        (date '2021-01-01'),
        (date '2021-01-01'),
        (date '2021-01-02'),
        (date '2021-01-03'),
        (date '2021-01-03')
)

-- query
select start_date
    , sum(cnt) over (order by start_date ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 30 FOLLOWING) rolling_count_31_days
from (
    select start_date
        , count(*) cnt
    from dataset
    where year(start_date) = 2021 
    group by start_date
)
```

Output:

| start_date | rolling_count_31_days |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 6 |
| 2021-01-02 | 3 |
| 2021-01-03 | 2 |

If some dates are missing - checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69744008/presto-insert-missing-timestamps/69744370#69744370) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72141309/missing-dates-for-specific-identifiers-without-adding-extra-dates-when-this-iden/72141894#72141894) answer describing how to insert missing dates and insert dates into the group result with `cnt` set to 0.

Note that Trino ([the new name for PrestoSQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)) updated support for [`RANGE` frame type](https://trino.io/blog/2021/03/10/introducing-new-window-features.html#-full-support-for-frame-type-range) and you can implement this without need to insert missing rows.