# Error with Presto --> strings and parsing dates

Tags: sql, database, date, datetime, presto

dear community!

I'm a bit lost with my SQL query on PRESTO. Essentially, I have a view with the following columns:

branch    | year_month (varchar)  |   sellid    [... and others]

Germany   |  2022-06        |        123q1239

What I need to do is fairly simple, I need to create a table like this:

branch      | year_month | count(sellid) actual month | count(sellid) last month

I attempted the following among other things, but unfortunately I'm still getting errors.

```
SELECT branch, year_month, count(sellid)as active_locs,
CASE
    WHEN TO_DATE(year_month, '%Y-%m') = date_format(TO_DATE(year_month, '%Y-%m') - interval '1' month, '%Y-%m') THEN count(sellid) END as locs_LM
FROM table
GROUP BY branch, year_month
```

This is the exact error I'm getting:

> An error occurred when executing the SQL command: SELECT branch,
> year_month, count(sellid)as active_locs, CASE
> WHEN TO_DATE(year_month, '%Y-%m') = date_format(TO_DATE(year_month, '%Y-%m') - interv...
>
> Query failed (#20220628_093246_00650_e4kcc): line 3:39: '=' cannot be
> applied to date, varchar [DB Errorcode=1] 1 statement failed.

Could someone help me out??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date_format` returns varchar while `TO_DATE` returns date, so you have type mismatch. Also you need to use `date_parse` with provided format:

```sql
SELECT branch, year_month, count(sellid)as active_locs,
CASE
    WHEN year_month = date_format(date_parse(year_month, '%Y-%m') - interval '1' month, '%Y-%m') THEN count(sellid) END as locs_LM
FROM dataset
GROUP BY branch, year_month
```

This will make query executing, but will not make it right. To make it right you can use [windows functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html) and subquery:

```sql
--sample data
WITH dataset(branch, year_month, sellid) AS (
    VALUES ('Germany', '2022-06', '123q1239'),
        ('Germany', '2022-05', '123q1239')
)

-- sample query
SELECT branch,
    date_format(year_month, '%Y-%m') year_month,
    active_locs,
    if( -- if previous record is for previous month use previous active_locs
        lag(year_month) over (partition  by branch order by year_month) 
            = year_month - interval '1' month, 
        lag(active_locs) over (partition  by branch order by year_month),
        0
    ) locs_LM
FROM (
        SELECT branch,
            date_parse(year_month, '%Y-%m') year_month,
            count(sellid) as active_locs
        FROM dataset
        GROUP BY 1,
            2
    )
```

Output:

| branch | year_month | active_locs | locs_LM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Germany | 2022-05 | 1 | 0 |
| Germany | 2022-06 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Thanks @Guru!! That already works. It makes it a bit tedious to work with since I'm also supposed to get the # of active locations for the last 12 months as columns too, but you didn't know of course.

Comment: I did, but it would be cool if you could help me understand how to extend the code to get the rest of the months too

Comment: @MarcosMicheloni if you rows for all year_month-branch combinations then just use `lag(active_locs, months_to_go_back) over(...)`  (`lag(active_locs, 2`) for month before previous, etc.) instead of `if`, if you have gaps - fill them in (for example like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69744370/2501279) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72141894/2501279)) and use my previous advice.