# Trino: Create a dynamic list of dates to fill values

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I was looking for a way to dynamically create a list of dates to join a table against, so that missing dates would be filled in.

Something like:

```
SELECT dt.date_col
     , ot.*
 FROM date_table AS dt -- Table with all dates?
 LEFT JOIN orig_table AS ot
   ON ot.date_col = dt.date_col
```

Comment: There are several answers for similar issues. For example created by myself [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69744370/2501279), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72141894/2501279) (though the insertion is done in-place, not via a separate table)

Comment: @GuruStron Interesting, those do appear to use a similar(/obscured same) method at their core. The first one doesn't seem to work if `orig_table` columns aren't unique, and would get complicated quickly the more columns were needed. What benefits are there to that method over this one?

Comment: As you mention - the idea is the same, the goal is a bit different. As for preference - without checking the execution it is hard to say, but bear in mind, ATM Presto/Trino has array size limit of 10k, so if you have a big date range with small gaps the linked approaches can be preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer in a coworker's code, but didn't see it on SO.

```
SELECT date_col
  FROM
UNNEST(sequence(date '2021-01-01', current_date, INTERVAL '1' DAY)) t (date_col)
```

So, in my example above, this could be used like:

```
WITH date_table AS (
    SELECT date_col
      FROM
    UNNEST(sequence(date '2021-01-01', current_date, INTERVAL '1' DAY)) t (date_col)
)
SELECT dt.date_col
     , ot.*
  FROM date_table AS dt
  LEFT JOIN orig_table AS ot
    ON ot.date_col = dt.date_col
```

Comment: This should be marked as answer

Comment: @viru ty for the reminder, you can't mark your own answer as the chosen answer until the day after creating it, and I'd forgotten to come back and do so.